# How to change back annotation pin color to original?

Tags: ios, ios6, mkmapview, mkannotation, ios6-maps

I am change annotation pin color when clicking annotation pin and click another annotation pin change pin color so currently two annotation color changed,but i want currently choosing annotation color only changed old selection back to original color.
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution create a

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) MKAnnotationView *selectedAnnotationView;
```

in .h file and save when clicked in annotation pin

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
if (self.selectedAnnotationView) {
    self.selectedAnnotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString    stringWithFormat:@"a.png"]];
}
self.selectedAnnotationView = view;
view.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"b.png"]];
}
```

change in .m file

Comment: You don't need to do `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"b.png"]` you can just use `@"b.png"`.